# MSFT Partner Network Windows 8 Enterprise upgrade to Windows 8.1 - No Apps option

Tags: windows-8

We have Windows 8 Enterprise, using the ISO and license key from the MSFT Partner Network.

The ISO for Windows 8.1 Enterprise is already available. We downloaded it, and when try to use it the options are: "Keep personals files" and "Keep nothing".

No option to "keep apps and settings".

Any advise?

Comment: Sounds like the 8.1 license isn't Enterprise. Verify it is.

Comment: More information is here: http://www.programmerfish.com/how-to-upgrade-to-windows-8-1-without-losing-apps/#.UugVtU8o4y8 verify the language is the same.

Comment: @Ramhound: Windows 8 is Enterprise edition and it is properly licensed. The ISO for Windows 8.1 was downloaded directly from the MSFT partner site and it is also the Enterprise edition. The installation doesn't ask for any license key.

Comment: Verify the language is the same.

Comment: That might be it. Seems that my original installation was done with the media for 'english' and the new media is for 'english international'. I am downloading the 'english' one now - that's probably it. Thanks (if you reply in the answers, and this is the solution I'd flag it as the answer).

Comment: Feel free to answer it yourself.  It's a good self-answer question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Ramhound mentioned, my issue was that the language of my Windows 8.1 Enterprise media didn't correspond to my installation.

Once I used the same language the option to "Keep Windows settings, personal files, and apps" showed up.

Side note: I do not know how MSFT is unable to include a simple warning message about this in the setup like "Hey... you are using a media with a language that doesn't match your current install".