# Upgrade windows 8.1 to 8.1 enterprise

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-8.1-upgrade

I'm trying to upgrade windows 8.1 to 8.1 enterprise with a product key from MSDN but it says my key is not valid when I use the "Add feature to windows" utility.

> This key won't work. Check it and try again, or try a different key

Then I tried with the .ISO but I don't have the option the keep the installed apps. I have only the option to keep the personal files or nothing.

Then I found this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/708337/msft-partner-network-windows-8-enterprise-upgrade-to-windows-8-1-no-apps-optio) saying that you need to remove the language packs but it still doesn't work.

The current Windows display language is English (Canada) in the PC Settings.
I downloaded the Windows 8.1 enterprise update (English) .iso

There are English Uk and English but no English (Canada) on the MSDN download website.

I don't know if it could be the problem

Comment: The language and region must match exactly to upgrade from any version of `Windows 8.0` to `Windows 8.1`.  Once you do that you can upgrade to `Windows 8.1 Professional` through the utility.  But you can't use the utility to go from Professional to Enterprise anyways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot perform an in-place upgrade from a plain-jane Windows 8.1 to 8.1 Enterprise; you need at least Windows 8 Pro.

From Microsoft's [Windows 8 and Windows 8.1 Upgrade Paths](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj203353.aspx):

> You can upgrade to Windows 8.1 Enterprise (Volume License) from the following operating system editions:
>
> ```
> • Windows 8 Pro
> • Windows 8 Pro with Media Center
> • Windows 8 Enterprise
> • Windows 8.1 Pro
> ```

Comment: Shame I requested my last key for 8.1 enterprise. All I need is bitlocker and it's avalaible with Windows 8.1 Pro. Thank you

Comment: You also can't upgrade to Enterprise through the `Add feature to windows` utility anyways.  You can do an in-place upgrade following the supported upgrade paths though.

Comment: I managed to get a key for Windows 8.1 pro and it works! Thank you!